# Javascript width and height variable to %

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I started a script and it started to by 600px x 600px. I now wish to change the script to change to % instead of px
Here is the code i'm currently using

```
    config.width = (typeof config.width === "undefined") ? 600 : config.width;
    config.height = (typeof config.height === "undefined") ? 600 : config.height;
```

How would I change 600 to 100%, If I change it to 100% I get resource not found.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried make '100%' as string?

Comment: Did you try `100%` or `"100%"`?